# Strange decompilation when using gcc with different optimization

Tags: c, gcc, reverse-engineering, radare2

I am running on linux 5.4.18-1-MANJARO with gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC)

Filename:a.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int
main(void) {
    int a;

    scanf("%d", &a);

    if (a < 5 || a > 6)
        puts("fail");
    else
        puts("succeed");
}
```

Then I run:

```
gcc a.c -O0 -o a.out
gcc a.c -O1 -o b.out
```

I decompile a.out with r2, and I got this

```
undefined8 main(void)
{
    undefined8 uVar1;
    int64_t in_FS_OFFSET;
    int32_t var_ch;
    int64_t canary;

    canary = *(int64_t *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28);
    sym.imp.__isoc99_scanf(0x2004, &var_ch);
    if ((var_ch < 5) || (6 < var_ch)) {
        sym.imp.puts("fail");
    } else {
        sym.imp.puts("succeed");
    }
    uVar1 = 0;
    if (canary != *(int64_t *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28)) {
        uVar1 = sym.imp.__stack_chk_fail();
    }
    return uVar1;
}
```

This is what I expected.

But when I decompile b.out, I got this

```
undefined8 main(void)
{
    undefined8 uVar1;
    undefined8 extraout_RDX;
    int64_t iVar2;
    int32_t *piVar3;
    uint32_t uVar4;
    int64_t in_FS_OFFSET;
    int32_t iStack20;
    int64_t iStack16;

    iStack16 = *(int64_t *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28);
    piVar3 = &iStack20;
    sym.imp.__isoc99_scanf(0x2004, piVar3);
    if (iStack20 - 5U < 2) {
        uVar4 = 0x200c;
        sym.imp.puts("succeed");
    } else {
        uVar4 = 0x2007;
        sym.imp.puts("fail");
    }
    if (iStack16 != *(int64_t *)(in_FS_OFFSET + 0x28)) {
        sym.imp.__stack_chk_fail();
        sym._init();
        iVar2 = 0;
        do {
            uVar1 = (**(code **)(segment.LOAD3 + iVar2 * 8))((uint64_t)uVar4, piVar3, extraout_RDX);
            iVar2 = iVar2 + 1;
        } while (iVar2 != 1);
        return uVar1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which seems only check if iStack20 < 7, and b.out runs fine.

I don't understand how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, an integer underflow is exploited. The operation

```
iStack20 - 5U
```

is performed *unsigned* due to the implicit conversion rules when the two operands differ in type (C standard 6.3.1.8(1)):

> Otherwise *[signedness differs]*,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has  rank  greater  or
>   equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other  operand,  then  the  operand  with
>   signed  integer  type  is  converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned
>   integer type.

So if `iStack20` is < 5, then the result will be very large (somewhere near `UINT_MAX`) , hence the comparison

```
iStack20 - 5U < 2
```

will be false. If `iStack20` is > 6, then the result will be greater than 2 anyway. So the program logic is preserved.